# Configurar transações do Hibernate somente com annotations da API do Jersey

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jersey

Eu quero utilizar algo similar ao `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` do Spring que configura uma Transação só que utilizando apenas a API do Jersey. Algo parecido com o código que segue abaixo:

```java
@Resource
private SessionFactory factory;

private Class<E> entity;

private String tableName;

public DataProvider(Class e) {
    this.entity = e;
    this.tableName = entity.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public E get(final Long ID) {
    return (E)factory.getCurrentSession().get(entity, ID);
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> getAll() {
    Session s = factory.getCurrentSession();
    return s.createQuery("FROM " + tableName ).list();
}
```

É possivel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, não é possível fazer com o Jersey controle transações do Hibernate.

Entenda que Jersey é feito para comunicação REST e não tem nada haver com transação do hibernate.

Você poderia utilizar CDI para realizar o controle de transação, mas não tem nada haver com Jersey.

Com CDI você precisa criar um Interceptor:

```
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@InterceptorBinding
public @interface Transaction {
    boolean readOnly() default true;
}
```

E depois você criaria seu interceptador como:

```
@Interceptor @Transaction(readOnly = false)
public class MethodWithTransaction {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object manageTransaction(InvocationContext context) throws Exception{
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;
        try{
            transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            Object methodResult = context.proceed();
            transaction.commit();
            return methodResult;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            if(transaction != null && transaction.isActive()){
                transaction.rollback();
            }

            throw ex;
        }finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Para utilizar você aplicaria como:

```
@Transaction(readOnly = false)
public void fazAlgo(){
    //
}
```

A única diferença é que você precisará criar um interceptor para quando o readOnly for true.

Comment: Apenas para completar, desde o Java EE 7 já é possível utilizar a anotação  [`Transactional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) diretamente em beans administrados pelo CDI (ou seja, em servidores de aplicação como o Wildfly e o Glassfish 4 basta anotar o bean, você não precisará implementar os interceptors). Em containers servlet (Tomcat, Jersey, etc) você precisa configurar as implementações na mão  (e.g , Weld + Hibernate + Atomikos)

Answer (score 2):

Caso esteja usando um servidor de aplicações como Wildfly, você pode fazer com que seu serviço seja também um EJB Stateless (adicione @Stateless no topo da classe), e todos os métodos REST serão automaticamente envolvidos em uma transação.

Caso não esteja usando, porquê não? Pelo quem e parece, você vai acabar fazendo uma integração manual que já está pronta para uso em servidores Java EE "completos"...

Comment: Existem diversos motivos para não usar um JBoss ou Glassfish da vida. Não ter que acoplar EJB já é um bom motivo. Para ser um arquiteto java, por exemplo, na prova você tem que responder em que casos EJB não são aconselháveis. [=

Comment: "Não ter que acoplar EJB já é um bom motivo" -- Não, o motivo é saber os pontos fortes e fracos de EJB. EJB por si só não é desvantagem.

Comment: Dependendo do seu sistema, sim EJB será desvantagem. Foi isso que eu quiz dizer. [=

Comment: @uaiHebert,  sem querer entre flamewars, esse é o típico caso em que EJBS são aconselháveis: necessidade de transações e uma camada de negócios acessando JPA (quase não existe diferença de performance entre  managed beans do CDI e stateless session beans do EJB). Além disso hoje em dia considero a plataforma Java EE bem mais prática que o Spring. Como diria Bob Dylan, *The times they are a changin*.

Comment: Eu creio que tudo vai da necessidade. C você vai rodar apenas um projeto de CRUD e tem máquina limitada, o Tomcat é uma ótima saída. Ou seja, eu sempre vejo que vai do requisito. [=